# UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: causes main window to disappear

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to present a modal mail dialogue like so in the iPad app:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;          
[picker setSubject:title];
[picker setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self emailBody], title, [link absoluteString]] isHTML:YES];
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

The following delegate is called when the user sends/cancels:

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error { 
    [self.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This works great in portrait mode.  In landscape mode the right hand pane of the UISplitViewController completely disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only present these from the primary view of your application.  In this case, presenting from the UISplitViewController works.